Drupal Entity print pdf token for Webform Rest Handler
I have a webform that uses webform remote handlers Drupal module to send the data in custom json format, with files in base 64.
I need to include the base64 of pdf created by webform enitity print attachment there as well.
When I use just [webform_submission:values], the URL of the file is included.
I include files from fields like this
{"file": [
      {
        "data": "[webform_submission:files:proof_of_identity]",
        "name": "proof_of_identity-[webform_submission:values:proof_of_identity:name]"
      }
    ]},

Can anyone help me if there is a token for the generated pdf that I can include in the message?
Thank you!
